# Unable to call pyvenv-activate from init file

Tags: init-file, elpy, customization

```
M-x pyvenv-activate <RET>
~/Documents/bitbucket-python-scripts/.env353 <RET>
```

works fine. Elpy Config buffer confirms that.

However with the following in ~/.emacs file

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(advice-add 'python-mode :before 'elpy-enable)
(elpy-enable)
(custom-set-variables
 '(elpy-rpc-python-command "python3")
 '(python-shell-interpreter "python3")
 '(pyvenv-activate "~/Documents/bitbucket-python-scripts/.env353"))
```

when I start Emacs and

```
M-x elpy-config
```

I see in the Elpy Config buffer that the virtual environment is  not set. custom-set-variables
were generated by Customization option of Emacs

Please point out my error.

Using:
Elpy 1.28.1
Emacs 24.5.1
Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)

UPDATED

```
(pyvenv-activate "~/Documents/bitbucket-python-scripts/.env353")
```

In ~/.emacs just after (elpy-enable) properly activate the virtual environment .env353. I have no idea why custom-set-variable command (obtained through customization) doesn't work.

Comment: Immediately I notice that `custom-set-variables` sets variables whereas `pyvenv-activate` is a function.  If you check `C-h v`, my guess is that you now have a variable called `pyvenv-activate` whose value is the given path.  The `elpy-rpc-python-command` and `python-shell-interpreter` should be okay, as those are indeed variables.  Try breaking out the `pyvenv-activate` statement and see how that works.

Comment: (pyvenv-activate ...) works fine. I was following the recommendations from https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/wiki/Configuration. They advised to use Elpy Config buffer and customization within.

Comment: Hmm, it is somewhat confusing that there is a `pyvenv-activate` variable *and* function.  I notice that the documentation for the variable states, "This is rarely useful to set globally", whatever that implies.  It seems that the `pyvenv-activate` variable only holds the path to the venv.  It doesn't activate it.  The function call is what activates it and that's not being called after you assign the `pyvenv-activate` variable.

Comment: ```pyvenv``` needs to know the execution path for ```python```, so add that path in your init file. Depends on operating system.